# Unable to use RAFT Optical Flow in Google Collab

Tags: github, conda, google-colaboratory, opticalflow

First timer to StackOverflow. I'm a student who is currently trying to work on a school project using Princeton Vision Lab's raft optical flow model and I am having a tough time. I want to use it and run it in google collab but am having a tough time setting up the conda environment to install and also load in a pre-trained model properly (which are on their github repo)

This is the first time I am doing something like this so I'm feeling really lost and out of the blue. Any help would be appreciated! I have some code of what I am trying to do below!
`# conda install

This is the readme and repo i am trying to follow from: https://github.com/princeton-vl/RAFT#readme

!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

`#conda update to avoid inconsistencies`
`!conda install anaconda`
`!conda update --all`
`!conda update conda -y -q;;`
`!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`
`!conda init bash`
`!conda install -n root _license -y -q`
`# raft setup`
`!conda create --name raft`
`!conda activate raft`
`` !conda install pytorch=1.6.0 torchvision=0.7.0 cudatoolkit=10.1 matplotlib tensorboard scipy opencv -c pytorch` ``

THANK you!

I have tried googling it to find other models that are installed using conda on Google Collab and trying to use their code but replace the optical flow model with RAFT instead of FlowNet or GMA but am having a tough time. I also tried to just isntall cuda normally and go from there but hac issues with conda install and inconsistnet enviorments (which is why I have the update conda line there as well)

Comment: Colab cannot use alternate environments - instead the strategy is to sideload Conda-installed packages into the existing Python on Colab. I recommend using [`condacolab`](https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab) and reading their docs.

Comment: Thank you! That did fix the environment issue but I had to end up installing conda a different way anyways because of some python version issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I use RAFT in Google Colab, CUDA must be enabled. You can see this [notebook](https://github.com/itberrios/CV_projects/blob/main/RAFT/RAFT_exploration.ipynb)  for details, but here are the basic steps.

1. Clone the repo:
   `!git clone https://github.com/princeton-vl/RAFT.git`
2. Add RAFT to core path: `sys.path.append('RAFT/core')`
3. Download RAFT models: `%cd RAFT` `!./download_models.sh` `%cd ..`
4. Add method to interface with RAFT, to use the RAFT code outside of the commandline it needs to either be modified or we can make a special class to interface with it which is what is shown below"

```
class Args():
  def __init__(self, model='', path='', small=False, mixed_precision=True, alternate_corr=False):
    self.model = model
    self.path = path
    self.small = small
    self.mixed_precision = mixed_precision
    self.alternate_corr = alternate_corr

  """ Sketchy hack to pretend to iterate through the class objects """
  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    raise StopIteration
```

5. Load a model:

```
def load_model(weights_path, args):
    model = RAFT(args)
    pretrained_weights = torch.load(weights_path, map_location=torch.device("cpu"))
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
    model.load_state_dict(pretrained_weights)
    model.to("cuda")
    return model

model = load_model("RAFT/models/raft-sintel.pth", args=Args())
```

Now you can run inference on a pair of image frames:

```
flow_iters = model(frame1, frame2, iters=12, test_mode=False)
```